# Split XML file into chunks after tag

Tags: xml, bash, sed

I have an XML file that's ~1GB big, with

```
grep -c "</record>')," file
238613
```

I'd like to split it into chunks of 1000 records, but each file needs to end with

```
</record>'),
```

I would then end up with 238 files.

Here is the actual file with the first two records:

```
\set bib_tag '''IMPORT CONCERTO'''
INSERT INTO marcxml_import (tag, marc) VALUES
(:bib_tag,'<record xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
<datafield and subfield data>
</record>'),
(:bib_tag,'<record xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
<datafield and subfield data>
</record>'),
```

Comment: Please post a sample of your data. If it is sensitive, make up something.

Comment: dive in (http://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html)

Comment: I added the file with the first two records

Answer (score 0):

You should use a language or program which support XML parsing. You could choice one of them in this following list :

Perl, Python, Ruby, PHP-cli (with SimpleXMLElement and Xpath for example), xmllint, etc

You should avoid regular expressions to do that task.

Here is an example of using a php shell script with Xpath queries : https://stackoverflow.com/a/20940216/2900196

Answer (score 0):

You could write a small XSLT script to split the file.

Using a template, a for-each loop and a result-document should be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Using gnu awk

```
awk '{print $0 RS >NR ".xml"}' RS="</record>')," file
```

After run, you should get several xml (or hundreds)

```
cat 1.xml

set bib_tag '''IMPORT CONCERTO'''
INSERT INTO marcxml_import (tag, marc) VALUES
(:bib_tag,'<record xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
<datafield and subfield data>
</record>'),
```

Comment: you can install GNU awk in mac.

Answer (score 0):

At least on Mac you can split files simply with the split command:

```
split -p "</record>')," file bib_snippet_
```

-p argument for pattern

**Update**: since you're required the files to end with "..record..." you need to manually add this yourself in this approach:

```
for f in `ls bib_snippet_*` ; do cat "</record>')," >> $f ; done
```